# sum labels from two gridview 1 and gridview 2 asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want sum of one column in gridview1 in label, and sum of one column in gridview2.After that i want to sum that two labels in page load.I sum column of gridview1 when I add row on button click, and also for gridview2.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of the values from the data source directly for 1 gridview when using the **[RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** . You can then store the total sum in a variable, and use that to populate the "Total" sum that you are after. To get the sum of a column from a specific grid view you can use the following code;

```
var gv= sender as GridView;
var ds= gv.DataSource as IEnumerable<YourClassObject>;
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = dataSource.Sum(item => item.YourProperty).ToString();
```

You can then assign labels, or cell text directly from the populated variable...